# Avalonia preview pan Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, avalonia

Maybe it's a stupid question and I'm sorry for that.
But how can I add preview pan to Avalonia in Visual Studio.
The tutorial says that a preview is available for the MainWindow.xaml file in Visual Studio, but I can't find how to add it in any way.
I tried to find answer but without success.
I have been looking all over the internet and I cannot find how to do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you install the visual studio extension?

Comment: It helped. I thought I installed it, but after checking it, I won't find it. Thanks